# Tools for static function discovery

Tags: disassembly, x86, static-analysis

In the case of static function discovery based on disassembled code, IDA is the best tool I know. What open source tools or frameworks are also able to perform function detection/analysis?

I know radare2 does have some code for that, but it isn't similar to IDA's detection. The architecture is mainly x86/x86_64, but also ARM.

Comment: Try this thesis by Cristina Cifuentes before reaching for tools http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.6048&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are several free disassemblers availables:

- [radare2](http://radare.org), which is also a framework. If you don't like its internal analysis capabilities, you can always use its shell to conduct your analysis by hand with it; it's released under LGPL, and written in C.
- [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/), the spiritual successor of [ollydbg](http://ww.ollydbg.de), but as a free software; it's Windows only, and written in C++/Qt.
- [HTE](http://hte.sourceforge.net/index.html), which seems to be a bit like radare2.

Comment: There's some tools designed for specific purposes as well. For example, mcsema includes bin_descend which is designed to recover a cfg. Unfortunately, that's a task ida is probably the best at.

Comment: Another one: pyew https://github.com/joxeankoret/pyew

Answer (score 0):

From your question is not clear if you mean *known* functions or arbitrary ones (a way more complicated problem).

For the first case you could take a look at Sybil (https://github.com/cea-sec/Sibyl)

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to using Ollydbg a lot, there is a plugin called [Godup](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.54). I used it on a daily basis when analyzing Delphi binaries since it contains IDA signatures that can be applied to a file being analyzed in Ollydbg. I believe it is not limited on only Delphi binaries, but based on my work so far that is the area where I used it the most. It saves me quite a lot of time with its function discovery functionality.